# PHP number format without comma

Tags: php

I want to display the number 1000.5 like 1000.50 with 2 decimal places and no commas/thousands separators.

I am using number_format to achieve this:

```
number_format(1000.5, 2);
```

This results 1,000.50. The comma (,) separator appended in thousand place which is not required in the result.

How can I display the number with a trailing zero and no comma?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

See the documentation for number_format: http://php.net/number_format

The functions parameters are:

> `string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )`

So use:

```
number_format(1000.5, 2, '.', '');
```

Which means that you don't use any (= empty string) thousands separator, only a decimal point.

Comment: Thanks for this! Not including the comma is particularly important if you later convert your formatted number using `intval()`, `floatval()` or `doubleval()`. Any number with a comma in it will become `1`!

Comment: this answer helped me today in dealing with a similar issue in my php script, I appreciate your help Sir.

Comment: This helped me in a situation where I needed to convert a product price for use with Schema.

Comment: Useful for when Google Analytics misinterprets revenue over 1000 (or 1,000)

Answer (score 20):

`number_format()` takes additional parameters:

```
number_format(1000.5, 2, '.', '');
```

The default is a period (`.`) for the decimal separator and a comma (`,`) for the thousands separator. I'd encourage you to [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation of number_format](http://php.net/manual/function.number-format.php) contains information about the parameter `string $thousands_sep = ','`. So this should work:

```
number_format(1000.5, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
number_format(1000.5, 2, '.', '');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php