# How do I get rid of php decimals

Tags: php, rounding

I am trying to calculate BMI using this simle php expression:

```
$bmi = $weight/pow($height, 2);
```

weight: 70
height: 170
it outputs: 0.0024221453287197

but the correct result must be: 24.22, how to get rid of all these decimals and zeros, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP number format without comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028946/php-number-format-without-comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this..

```
$num = 0.0024221453287197;

// move the decimal right 4 places.
$num = $num * 10000;

// format the number
echo number_format($num, 2);
```

Tested at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b95dd43a426b5d55bf1fddd9faf7b13116908192.

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the input by 100.

`echo $weight/pow($height/100, 2); // 24.221453287197`

Test online: https://3v4l.org/VIh0r